# GOTO statements not working as expected in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'model')
    BEGIN
        GOTO CREATESCEDB;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        GOTO UPDATESCEDB;
    END

CREATESCEDB:
PRINT 'Create'
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [model]     
GO
GOTO ENDOFSCRIPT

UPDATESCEDB:
PRINT 'Update'
GOTO ENDOFSCRIPT

ENDOFSCRIPT:
PRINT 'END'
```

In above sql query, if I remove

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [model]     
GO
```

then it works fine otherwise not. 
Having

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [model]     
GO
```

in the query always run `CREATE DATABASE [model]` . Do not know why.

Comment: `GO` terminates a batch.  The `goto` labels are not recognized across batches.

Comment: But, why cursor goes to CREATESCEDB portion at all? It should go to UPDATESCEDB. Isnt it?

Comment: Can you suggest any other way to achieve the same function in sql? I don't want to have two separate files for Create and Update my database.

Comment: The only way to run something in another data within a batch (that I can think of) is to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

`GOTO` will not work across batches. The `GO` keyword terminate a batch. It's just like you had different scripts, i.e.:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'model')
    BEGIN
        GOTO CREATESCEDB;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        GOTO UPDATESCEDB;
    END

CREATESCEDB:
PRINT 'Create'
USE [master]
```

GO

```
CREATE DATABASE [model]
```

GO

```
GOTO ENDOFSCRIPT

UPDATESCEDB:
PRINT 'Update'
GOTO ENDOFSCRIPT

ENDOFSCRIPT:
PRINT 'END'
```

So you can jump to `CREATESCEDB` but not further. And you should see the error:

> Msg 133, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 A GOTO statement references the
>   label 'UPDATESCEDB' but the label has not been declared.

Answer (score 0):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185681

In response to your request for a suggested alternate, the syntax might use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'model')
      BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
        USE master;
        CREATE DATABASE [model];'
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        PRINT 'Update'; 
      END
```